# How do I execute a javascript method attached to a button in webdriver?

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to execute a javascript method that is attached to a button in webdriver.

I have some thing like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id(Button)).click();
```

This button has an `"onclick=javascript:method()"` attached to it. So when i run the test on a browser it works fine. But if i run it in htmlunit the onclick method is not executed.

I tried something like this:

```
IJavascriptExecutor js = (IJavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("");
```

But not sure how to enter the method name in the " "

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options (following examples are in C#):

Trigger a click event via jQuery:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", element);
```

Trigger the click event via javascript:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

And last but not least, call the function directly:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("someFunction();");
```

Note that none of these are really preferable; you should look into configuring HtmlUnit properly so that the javascript works as expected.